# Login mechanism for external database

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have started developing ASP.NET MVC 4 application with the internet template. I want the login mechanism to work with an external database hosted on a full SQL server. The Internet template created by Visual Studio connects to a database on a localdb with SQLExpress. To make the login mechanism work with an external database I made the following changes:

**1. Created the aspnet_schema on my external database using aspnet_regsql.exe.**

**2. Changed the connection string in the web.config to reflect the externaldb.**

```
 <connectionStrings>
  <clear />
  <add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
    connectionString="Data Source=10.183.2.22\Sandbox,1432;
    Initial Catalog=ForecastView;Integrated Security=False;
    User ID=peak;Password=PvS20150401;
    Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False" />
 </connectionStrings>
```

**3.Added the provider configuration in the web.config.**

```
<profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
 <providers>
  <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" 
   type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, 
   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" 
   connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
 </providers>
</profile>
<membership defaultProvider="SqlProvider">
 <providers>
  <clear />
  <add name="SqlProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, 
   System.Web,Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" 
   connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
   enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" 
   requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" 
   minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" 
   passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
 </providers>
</membership>
<roleManager>
 <providers>
  <clear />
  <add connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" 
   name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, 
   System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
 </providers>
</roleManager>
```

With the above changes the login mechanism for an external db works if I use the Mobile Application template for ASP.NET MVC 4. How to make this work for the Internet template? Any help is greatly appreciated!!